# How do I calculate the 4th power of the Dirichlet integral with Fourier transforms?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I'm pretty new to Fourier Transforms and I stumbled upon this exercise, which asks me to calculate this integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}x\right)^4\,dx$$
The exercise suggests to use fourier transforms, but I really don't get how! I recognized that the term inside the parentheses is a Dirichlet integral, so I know its transform, which is $$\frac{1}2\sqrt\frac{\pi}2 \left(\text{sgn}(a-\lambda) +\text{sgn}(a+\lambda\right))$$ but I can't just multiply everything by $e^{-ia\lambda}$ as if were nobody's business! And then inside that integral I have the 4th power the transform, how do I deal with it?

Thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: Fourier transforms convert multiplication to convolution and vice versa.

Comment: you caould apply Paresval to the function $\sin^2( x)/x^2$ which is just the triangle function

Comment: @MarkViola fools seldom differ :p

Comment: @tired Yes.  They say that geniuses think alike.  But then again, so do fools.

Comment: @MarkViola haha... personally i am more on the foolish side ^^

Comment: @tired Unfortunately, I seem to be with you.

Comment: @MarkViola. Why do, you and "tired", invade my side (the foolish one) ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Calude, there's always room for one or two more.

Comment: @MarkViola. OK, welcome to **my** club ! Cheers.

Comment: Ok guys, I got it! The logic's very simple and I shouldn't have forgotten about parseval's identity.

HOWEVER! Calculations got me again, I'm stuck at

$$a^{4} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (sinc^2(\frac{ax}\pi))^2dx$$

What's the argument of the $tri(x)$ function after I apply Parseval's Identity?

Comment: Please don't be so sloppy with the parenthesises for functions. $\sin$ is a function.

Comment: My bad, I will edit

Comment: Is this the fourth power of an integral or the integral of a fourth power?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First note that enforcing the substitution $x\to x/a$, reveals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(ax)}{x^4}\,dx=a^3\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^4}\,dx$$

---

To find the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^4}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}\,dx$, we simply need to convolve the Fourier Transform of $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}$ with itself, and evaluate this at $\omega=0$.

---

> **PRIMER:  FOURIER-TRANSFORM PAIRS:**
>
> We have the Fourier Transform pairs
>
> $$\begin{align}
> f(x) &\leftrightarrow F(\omega)\\\\
> f^2(x) &\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}F(\omega)*F(\omega)\\\\
> \frac{\sin(x)}{x}&\leftrightarrow \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{rect}(\omega/2)\\\\
> \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}&\leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{rect}(\omega/2)\right)*\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{rect}(\omega/2)\right)=\sqrt{\frac\pi8}2 \text{tri}(\omega/2)
> \end{align}$$
>
> where $\text{rect}(t)$ and $\text{tri}(t)$ are the [Rectangle Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) and [Triangle Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function), respectively.

---

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(x)}{x^4}\,dx &=\left.\left(\left(\sqrt{\frac\pi8}2 \text{tri}(\omega/2)\right)*\left(\sqrt{\frac\pi8}2 \text{tri}(\omega/2)\right)\right)\right|_{\omega =0}\\\\
&=\int_{-2}^2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\frac{}{}(2-|\omega'|)\right)^2\,d\omega'\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\,2\int_0^2 (\omega'-2)^2\,d\omega'\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\,2\left(\frac83\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3}
\end{align}$$

Hence, we can assert that

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin^4(ax)}{x^4}\,dx=\frac{2\pi a^3}{3}}$$

Comment: You are a godsent, thanks you a ton! I always get lost in silly calculations like this

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: This is brilliant @MarkViola

Comment: @lelouch.d.light Wow.  Thank you.